# Facebook OauthException Code 2

Tags: facebook, node.js, oauth

I'm trying to query for page data and posts data using graph api. Suddenly, I'm getting OauthException error code 2. I'm using fbGraph module for nodejs. Does anyone know what is wrong? Here is my code:

```
var fbGraph = require('fbgraph');

var params = {

    access_token: userToken,
    limit: 500,
    since: moment(startDate).format(constants.DATE_FORMAT),
    until: moment(startDate).clone().add('months', 1).format(constants.DATE_FORMAT),
    fields: 'id,message,description,call_to_action,shares,likes,comments.limit(1000000).fields(id),application.fields(name)'
};

var url = '/' + facebookPageId + '/posts';

fbGraph.get(url, params, callback);
```